# Heroku producing 500 error when trying to send emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, sendgrid

I have a Rails application on Heroku that has started to produce 500 errors, I believe, when attempting to send emails – we use the SendGrid addon.

The error that I am seeing is this:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (certificate has expired)
```

Our certificates are managed by Heroku so I cannot see info about them in the Heroku control panel, but when I look at the certificate in Chrome it looks like they are valid until the end of July.

I have filed an issue with Heroku support, and am waiting for a response.

Update: Heroku said it was because their stack version 16 was an issue, and that I should upgrade to 18. I did that, but it did not help.

I have found that for some reason I am only apparently only getting this issue with Devise mailers.

I tested setting OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE and this solved the problem...

So now I’m not sure if Devise is doing something different than the other mailers, and if so why...

Comment: Can you add in your SMTP settings from the appropriate environment configuration file?

Comment: Starting to look like this was related to including Bootstrap via CDN and/or image tags and/or the premailer gem

Answer (score 0):

Heroku thought it might be an issue related to the Heroku-16 stack. They advised upgrading to version 18 stack.

I tried updating to v18 stack but it did not solve our problem.

I later added a log entry to inspect the full stack trace and it started to look like it involved the premailer gem.

I noticed that we were including Bootstap from a CDN in our templates, and that premailer was possibly failing in attempting to get that CSS.

I ended up getting rid of both premailer and the Bootstrap CSS (which was really doing much for us anyway).

This solved the problem, but I never really understood the actual cause and it may have been a result of the Sectigo certificate expiring on May 30 2020 as Heroku suggested and mhale mentioned in an answer to this question.

Comment: Oops that was not true.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've been affected by this root certificate expiry issue:
https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=23362759

You should confirm the version of openssl running on your Heroku dyno.

You can do that by running `heroku run openssl version -a YOUR_APP_NAME`.

You want version 1.1+ to avoid the above issue.

Comment: According to Heroku (here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack-packages ) their heroku-18 stack should have openssl 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.6 (as of this comment).

Comment: It looks like Heroku updated the root certificate. An app restart is required to load it. See: https://help.heroku.com/QTGUWT0Z/why-am-i-getting-an-ssl_connect-error-when-calling-external-services